# In forge viewer onSelectionEvent this.viewer.getProperties() method does not returns property information when site is opened on mobile

Tags: autodesk-forge

"In forge viewer version 6.* onSelectionEvent this.viewer.getProperties() method does not returns property information when site is opened on mobile but it works fine on desktop. “On mobile a property called propDbLoader is not generated which is responsible to pass the data to the viewer. The same method works fine in version 2.7.* for desktop and mobile both but does not work version 6.*, viewer.getProperties() returns undefined ,while debugging found that when site is opened in mobile its does not find the property propDbLoader under Model.prototype.getPropertyDb = function() {
    var data = this.g`enter code here`etData();
    return data && data.propDbLoader;
}; says data.propDbLoader  undefined.

```
 PanelObjectExtension.prototype.onSelectionEvent = function (event) {
       var viewer = this.viewerApp;
        var currSelection = this.viewer.getSelection();
        this.viewer.getProperties(currSelection[0], function (objProp) {
         if (objProp) {
              var Prop = objProp.properties[2];
             if (Prop.displayName == 'Test' && Prop.displayValue == 'Test') {
                 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                     url:document.location.origin+'@Url.Action("TestAction", "Test")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{Test: "' + objProp["Test"] + '" }',
                     dataType: "json",
                     cache: false,
                     headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#Test).val(data.Test);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                            Console.log(errorMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }, function (xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
            Console.log(errorMessage);
            alert(errorMessage);
            });
        };
```

viewer.getProperties() should return the property information in forge viewer version 6.* .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue with Viewer v6.6 on iOS Safari - see live sample [here](https://output.jsbin.com/xuyupod):

```
viewer.getProperties(4, sb=>alert(JSON.stringify(sb))
```

[image]